# Shmita and Joseph's Dreams

Tags: number, parshanut-torah-comment, miketz, shmita

Shmita is every 7 years and we leave the land unused.
In Egypt there were 7 years of feast, then 7 years of famine.
As leaving the land unused could be considered famine like conditions, are there any sources that relate these two?

Shmita is often compared to creation, 7 day:7 years.
If this is the case the reverse question can be asked: were the feast and famine periods related to creation?

Or, neither are compared at all and seven is just a oft used number in Torah.

Comment: What do you mean by compared?

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7389/a-natural-explanation-for-the-significance-of-the-numbers-7-and-40

Comment: The Use of the number 7 in the dream, may be telling us that this was a natural cycle, and not a miraculous one done for Yoseph's benefit.

Answer (score 3):

The MaHaral says that the number 7 is the number of natural occurrence, while the number 8 is for supernatural. Therefore a baby has his Bris on the 8th day to show that we are L'Maalah M'Derech Hatevah. There are many things in the Torah with the number 7. 7 days of the week, 7 years in a Shemita cycle, 7 Shemitas then a Yoveil, and many other examples of 7. I have never seen anyone connecting Shemita which is only once in 7 years to the 7 years in a row of plenty and then 7 years in a row (cut short when Yaakov arrived) of famine.

Comment: It may also be worth bearing in mind that Shmita only applies in Eretz Yisroel (not Egypt).